# Socket is not sending/receiving over multi-threaded java program

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

I'm creating a chat for a game that runs on a server and client system, and then of course the game on the server client system, but I cannot get my multithreaded program to work, and I'll explain how below. What I can say is the server client system works when single threaded.

To start, my connection class:

```
public class Connection {

private Server server;
private Client client;
private boolean serverChosen;

public Connection(){
    server = new Server();
    this.serverChosen = true;
}

public Connection(String IP){
    client = new Client(IP);
    this.serverChosen = false;
}
public synchronized void sendObjects(Object obj) throws IOException{
    if(serverChosen){
        server.sendObjects(obj);
    }else{
        client.sendObjects(obj);
    }

}   
public synchronized Object receiveObjects() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
    if(serverChosen){
        return server.receiveObjects();
    }else{
        return client.receiveObjects();
    }
}

public Object waitForObject() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
    int i = 0;
    Object obj;
    while(true){
        obj = receiveObjects();
        i++;
        if(obj != null || i >= 100){
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Server and Client classes:

```
public class Server implements Serializable{



private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;

//constructor
public Server(){

    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(8790, 10); //8798 is a dummy port for testing, this can be changed. The 100 is the maximum people waiting to connect.
            try{
                //Trying to connect and have conversation
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
            }catch(EOFException eofException){
            }
    } catch (IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//wait for connection, then display connection information
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
    connection = server.accept();
}

//get stream to send and receive data
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();

    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

}


public ObjectOutputStream getOutput(){
    return output;
}
public ObjectInputStream getInput(){
    return input;
}

public void sendObjects(Object obj) throws IOException{
        output.writeObject(obj);
        output.flush();

}   
public Object receiveObjects() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        return input.readObject();
}

}

public class Client extends JFrame implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;

private String serverIP;
private Socket connection;
private boolean next = true;

//constructor
public Client(String host){

    serverIP = host;

    try{
        connectToServer();
        setupStreams();
    }catch(EOFException eofException){
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Client(){

    serverIP = "127.0.0.1";

    try{
        connectToServer();
        if(next){
                setupStreams();
        }
    }catch(EOFException eofException){
        //t.append("Connection was terminated");
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}



//connect to server
private void connectToServer(){
    int i = 0;
    do {
        try {
            connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 8790);
            next = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server was not found, The program will try again in 1 second; number of tries left: " + (10-i));
            next = false;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }while(!next && i<=10);
    if(!next){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to connect to the server. Make sure the I.P. adress is correct, the ports are not blocked, or a firewall has not prevented connections.... IDK man... it's just me and all of this code... maybe the server isn't even running??");
    }
}

//set up streams
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
}



public ObjectOutputStream getOutput(){
    return output;
}
public ObjectInputStream getInput(){
    return input;
}

public void sendObjects(Object obj) throws IOException{
        output.writeObject(obj);
        output.flush();

}

public Object receiveObjects() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
        return input.readObject();
}

}
```

The class I'm running everything on is the Frame class:

```
public class Frame implements ActionListener{

private int width;
private int height;
private JFrame jframe;
private Board board;
private JTextArea textBox;
private JScrollPane pane;
private Connection connection;
private JTextArea userText;
private JScrollPane userPane;
private JButton send;
private NetworkReceiver net;


public Frame(int width, int height, Connection connection, Board player, Board opponent){
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.connection = connection;

board = new Board(player, opponent);
init();
textBox = new JTextArea("CHAT WINDOW");
textBox.setWrapStyleWord(true);
textBox.setLineWrap(true);
textBox.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
textBox.setBounds(height, 0, width - (height) - 20, height-40);
textBox.setEditable(false);

userText = new JTextArea("Enter Messages Here");
userText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
userText.setLineWrap(true);
userText.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
userText.setBounds(height, height-40, width - (height) - 20, 40);

pane = new JScrollPane(textBox, 
        ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
pane.setBounds(height, 0, width - (height), height-40);

userPane = new JScrollPane(userText, 
        ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
userPane.setBounds(height, height-40, width - (height) - 20, 40);

send = new JButton();
send.setIcon(Utility.getImageIcon(Utility.getBufferedImage(Assets.send)));
send.setBounds(width - 20, height - 40, 20, 40);
send.addActionListener(this);
send.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


jframe = new JFrame();
jframe.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
jframe.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
jframe.setLayout(null);
jframe.pack();

jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
jframe.add(pane);
jframe.add(userPane);
jframe.add(send);

for(Space[] s: board.getSpaces()){
    for(Space space: s){
        jframe.add(space);
    }
}
for(Space[] s: board.getSpaces()){
    for(Space space: s){
        space.addActionListener(this);
    }
}

for(Space[] s: board.getSpaces()){
    for(Space space: s){
        if(space.getTile() != null){
            space.setBackground(space.getTile().getColor());
        }
    }
}
for(Space[] s: board.getSpaces()){
    for(Space space: s){
        if(space.getPiece() != null){
            space.setIcon(Utility.getImageIcon(space.getPiece().getImage()));
        }
    }
}

jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jframe.setVisible(true);

net = new NetworkReceiver(connection, this);
net.start();
}

private void init(){        
  //stuff
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(e.getSource() == send){
    send();
}

}

private synchronized void send() {
String message = "YOU- " + userText.getText();
userText.setText("");
String totalMessage = textBox.getText();
textBox.setText(totalMessage + "\n" + message);
new NetworkSender(connection, message).start();
}

public synchronized void showMessage(String s){
String totalMessage = "Opponent- " + textBox.getText();
textBox.setText(totalMessage + "\n" + s);
}
```

I do not want to delete anything more in the constructor above in case it is in some way causing the issue(which I doubt but since I cannot find the issue better safe than sorry)

Here is the NetworkSender and NetworkReceiver classes:

```
public class NetworkSender extends Thread{

private Connection c;
private String msg;

public NetworkSender(Connection c, String msg){
this.c = c;
this.msg = msg;
}

public void run(){
try {
    System.out.println("Trying to send");
    c.sendObjects(msg);
    System.out.println("Sent");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

}

public class NetworkReceiver extends Thread{

private Connection c;
private boolean running = true;
private Frame f;

public NetworkReceiver(Connection c, Frame f){
this.c = c;
this.f = f;
}

public void run(){
while(running){
    System.out.println("running");
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        obj = c.receiveObjects();
        System.out.println("received");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("failed - class exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("failed - IO exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        running = false;
    }
    if(obj != null){
        if(obj instanceof String){
            f.showMessage((String)obj);
        }
    }
}
}

public void kill(){
running = false;
}

}
```

The exact spot of breaking is in the NetworkSender class. In the console, I receive "Trying to send" but never "sent." This leads me to think that I'm setting up the threads wrong, the threads are somehow unable to talk to each other (sender and receiver threads), or the server/client system is done improperly for multi-threading.

I have looked up this issue extensively, but I could not find a solution anywhere that worked, so I apologize if there is a solution I over looked. If everything is checking out, I can post my connection, server, and client classes if needed, but I'm assuming they are functional since they work on the EDT. As I put nearly 4 hours scouring online, I ask that if you think this is a duplicate question you comment a link first, as I am almost sure I have seen it already lol.

Comment: This all looks pretty dubious, but you don't show the most important thing: Connection. You're probably deadlocking your threads with coarse synchronization in your connection class (e.g. NetworkReceiver holding a monitor on Connection blocking everything else). The entire code looks dubious to me, extends Thread and creating a new NetworkSender for every message all ring alarm bells.

Comment: @Durandal, Ill post my connection and server/client classes. The deadlocking sounds like it is possible, but I do not know enough about sockets to know for sure. I hope the new code helps you help me lol

Comment: Its pretty obvious, you are synchronizing both sending and receiving on the same object - the Connection. That means while the NetworkReceiver is waiting for data to be received *nothing* else can be sent. I would rethink the entire design, and especially carefully what is synchronized on which object. Also rethink were to put methods - I would reasonably expect the Connection class to represent one *endpoint* of a connection, no switching logic between client/server. If you base your Connection around the Socket object the need for a difference disappears.

Comment: Connection is either a server or a client. It never switches between them. I implemented it this way since so that I didn't need to make 2 different versions of the same game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate reason is that you synchronize both receiving and sending on the Connection object itself. Meaning while one thread is inside receiveObjects(), no other thread can enter either send or receiveObjects(). Thus your receiving thread permanently blocks you from sending.

You could potentially make it work by removing synchronized from the methods on your connection class and instead making the respective methods on your client and server synchronize *on selected different objects*, for example the respective Input/Output-Streams.

Still, its a design desaster (not mincing words here). Your best course of action is probably to rethink the design - your choice of abstractions (or rather the lack of) and the choices you made with regards to assignment of responsibilities leave room for improvement.

Comment: Potential immediate fixes are nice, but How should one go about it the right way? You mentioned lack of abstractions, which abstractions should be made? I appreciate the knowledge of why and where things are broken, and I'll look into it more now that I know what to look for. But if you could clarify some of the points you made I would be very gracious.

Comment: Its not like I dont want to tell you, the problem is to clarify everything I would need to write an excessive amount of text with class stubs to go along. It would bascially be a tutorial on *multiple* topics, like API design, socket programming, threading/synchronization and generics.

Comment: Regardless I appreciate the topics. I'll look into them and see what I can do.